# How do I convert a VARCHAR of 'YES' to a TINYINT of 1 into another table?

Tags: mysql

I have `tableA` and it has a column called `funny VARCHAR(4)` and it's filled with `'YES'` and `'NO'` strings.

I have `tableB` that also has the `funny TINYINT(1)` column and it's empty.

Assuming both tables have corresponding `id` columns, what's a MySQL query I can run from Workbench that will take everything from `tableA` and convert it into the correct integer value in `tableB`?

Comment: In MySQL `(funny = 'YES')` will evaluate to `1` for 'YES' and `0` for all other cases. [In SQL, all logical operators evaluate to TRUE, FALSE, or NULL (UNKNOWN). In MySQL, these are implemented as 1 (TRUE), 0 (FALSE), and NULL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html)

Comment: `Select ID, Case when funny='YES' then 1 when funny='NO' then 0 else null end as convert from tableA`  Hopefully you can figure out the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell mysql to fill up the insert statement with the needed information from `tableA` to `tableB` this way it will insert the new records, since you mentioned it is an empty table. the case statement will take care of changing the value from `yes/no` to `1/0` values.

```
INSERT INTO tableB (id, funny) 
(SELECT id, 
  CASE funny
    WHEN funny = 'YES' THEN 1
    WHEN funny = 'NO' THEN 0 
  END as funny_new
  FROM tableA )
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the answer. Answers only containing code are not recommended.